# Methods in Slope, Aspect SAGA calculations

Tags: qgis, algorithm, saga, slope, aspect

Using this algorithm in QGIS I can choose between 7 methods, the default one being by Zevenbergen & Thorne 1987. What's the difference between them and can I just use the default one without worrying about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default method is the most used for general tasks, but you can choose the best one for your case by reading the related documentation (taken from [SAGA-GIS Module Library Documentation (v2.1.3)](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.3/ta_morphometry_0.html):

> **(0) Maximum Slope (Travis et al. 1975)**
>
> Travis, M.R., Elsner, G.H., Iverson, W.D., Johnson, C.G. (1975):
> ['VIEWIT: computation of seen areas, slope, and aspect for land-use
> planning'](https://www.fs.fed.us/psw/publications/documents/psw_gtr011/gtr-011part1.pdf), USDA F.S. Gen. Tech. Rep. PSW-11/1975, 70p. Berkeley,
> California, U.S.A.
>
> **(1) Maximum Triangle Slope (Tarboton 1997)**
>
> Tarboton, D.G. (1997): ['A new method for the determination of flow
> directions and upslope areas in grid digital elevation models'](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/96WR03137/abstract), Water
> Ressources Research, Vol.33, No.2, p.309-319
>
> **(2) Least Squares Fitted Plane (Horn 1981, Costa-Cabral & Burgess 1996)**
>
> Horn, B. K. (1981): ['Hill shading and the relectance map'](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1456186/), Proceedings of the IEEE, v. 69, no. 1, p. 14-47.
>
> Beasley, D.B., Huggins, L.F. (1982): ['ANSWERS: User's manual'](https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyNET.exe/200074V9.TXT?ZyActionD=ZyDocument&Client=EPA&Index=1981%20Thru%201985&Docs=&Query=&Time=&EndTime=&SearchMethod=1&TocRestrict=n&Toc=&TocEntry=&QField=&QFieldYear=&QFieldMonth=&QFieldDay=&IntQFieldOp=0&ExtQFieldOp=0&XmlQuery=&File=D%3A%5Czyfiles%5CIndex%20Data%5C81thru85%5CTxt%5C00000000%5C200074V9.txt&User=ANONYMOUS&Password=anonymous&SortMethod=h%7C-&MaximumDocuments=1&FuzzyDegree=0&ImageQuality=r75g8/r75g8/x150y150g16/i425&Display=hpfr&DefSeekPage=x&SearchBack=ZyActionL&Back=ZyActionS&BackDesc=Results%20page&MaximumPages=1&ZyEntry=1&SeekPage=x&ZyPURL), U.S.
> EPA-905/9-82-001, Chicago, IL. 54pp.
>
> Costa-Cabral, M., Burges, S.J., (1994): ['Digital Elevation Model
> Networks (DEMON): a model of flow over hillslopes for computation of
> contributing and dispersal areas'](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/93WR03512/abstract), Water Resources Research, v. 30,
> no. 6, p. 1681-1692.
>
> **(3) 6 parameter 2nd order polynom (Evans 1979)**
>
> Evans, I.S. (1979): ['An integrated system of terrain analysis and
> slope mapping'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279893237_An_integrated_system_of_terrain_analysis_and_slope_mapping), Final report on grant DA-ERO-591-73-G0040. University
> of Durham, England.
>
> **(4) 6 parameter 2nd order polynom (Heerdegen & Beran 1982)**
>
> Heerdegen, R.G., Beran, M.A. (1982): ['Quantifying source areas through
> land surface curvature'](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002216948290155X), Journal of Hydrology, Vol.57
>
> **(5) 6 parameter 2nd order polynom (Bauer, Rohdenburg, Bork 1985)**
>
> Bauer, J., Rohdenburg, H., Bork, H.-R. (1985): ['Ein Digitales
> Reliefmodell als Vorraussetzung fuer ein deterministisches Modell der
> Wasser- und Stoff-Fluesse'](http://www.geomorphometry.org/content/ein-digitales-reliefmodell-als-vorraussetzung-fuer-ein-deterministisches-modell-der-wasser-u), Landschaftsgenese und
> Landschaftsoekologie, H.10, Parameteraufbereitung fuer
> deterministische Gebiets-Wassermodelle, Grundlagenarbeiten zu Analyse
> von Agrar-Oekosystemen, (Eds.: Bork, H.-R. / Rohdenburg, H.), p.1-15
>
> **(6) 9 parameter 2nd order polynom (Zevenbergen & Thorne 1987)**
>
> Zevenbergen, L.W., Thorne, C.R. (1987): ['Quantitative analysis of land
> surface topography'](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/esp.3290120107/abstract), Earth Surface Processes and Landforms, 12: 47-56.
>
> **(7) 10 parameter 3rd order polynom (Haralick 1983)**
>
> R.M. Haralick (1983): ['Ridge and valley detection on digital images'](http://www.geomorphometry.org/content/ridge-and-valley-detection-digital-images),
> Computer Vision, Graphics and Image Processing, Vol.22, No.1, p.28-38